# Как правильно прочитать разделы жесткого диска

Tags: c, windows, железо, borland-c++

Мне нужно прочитать все 4 раздела жесткого диска и вывести их на экран. С выводом все нормально а вот с чтением самих разделов проблема, я не понимаю что менять, головку, цилиндр или сектор. Пробовал менять все эти значения и всегда что то считывается из-за чего я не особо понимаю правильно ли я все прочитал. Программа написана на языке си в BorlandC++(TurboC), работаю в win98.

Код программы

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//#define NUM_PARTITIONS 4

unsigned char buf[512];

int read_mbr() {
    union REGS in, out;
    struct SREGS sr;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (; i < 64; i += 16, j++) {
    sr.es = FP_SEG(buf + i);
        in.x.bx = FP_OFF(buf + i);

        in.h.ah = 0x02;
        in.h.al = 1;
    in.h.dl = 0x80 + j;
    in.h.dh = 0;
    in.h.cl = 1;
    in.h.ch = 0;

        int86x(0x13, &in, &out, &sr);

    if (out.x.cflag || out.h.ah)
        return 1;

    printf("%d", j);
    }

    return 0;
}

int get_count_partitions() {                                         
    int numPartitions = 0;
    int i = 0x1BE;

    for (; i <= 0x1EE; i += 16) {
        numPartitions++;
    }

    return numPartitions;
}

void extract_partition_info(int partition_number) {
    unsigned char beginHd = buf[1];
    unsigned short beginSecCyl = *((unsigned short*)(buf + 2));

    // Print the extracted partition information
    printf("Partition %d:\n", partition_number);
    printf("Begin Hd: %u\n", beginHd);
    printf("Begin Sec/Cyl: %u\n", beginSecCyl);
}

void print_partition_info(unsigned char* partition_entry, int partition_number) {
    unsigned char bootFlag = partition_entry[0];
    unsigned char beginHd = partition_entry[1];
    unsigned short beginSecCyl = *((unsigned short*)(partition_entry + 2));
    unsigned char systemCode = partition_entry[4];
    unsigned char endingHd = partition_entry[5];
    unsigned short endingSecCyl = *((unsigned short*)(partition_entry + 6));
    unsigned int startingSector = *((unsigned int*)(partition_entry + 8));
    unsigned int numSectors = *((unsigned int*)(partition_entry + 0x0C));

    printf("Partition %d:\n", partition_number);
    printf("Boot Flag: 0x%02X\n", bootFlag);
    printf("Begin Hd: %u\n", beginHd);
    printf("Begin Sec/Cyl: %u\n", beginSecCyl);
    printf("System Code: 0x%02X\n", systemCode);
    printf("Ending Hd: %u\n", endingHd);
    printf("Ending Sec/Cyl: %u\n", endingSecCyl);
    printf("Starting Sector (LBA): %u\n", startingSector);
    printf("Number of Sectors: %u\n", numSectors);
    printf("Root Boot Sector Address (LBA): %u\n", startingSector);
}

int main() {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    clrscr();

    if (read_mbr())
        printf("Error reading sector\n");
    else
        printf("Sector read successfully\n");

    printf("Number of sections: %d\n", get_count_partitions());
    extract_partition_info(1);

    getch();
    clrscr();

    for(;j < 512; j++)
    printf("%d",(int)buf[j]);
    getch();

    for (; i < 64; i += 16){
    clrscr();
    print_partition_info(&buf[i], (i/16 + 1));
    getch();
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Какую именно информацию нужно вывести о разделе

```
Смещ.   Длина   Содержимое
+0      1       Boot Flag- флаг загрузки : 0=не активен, 80h = активен. 
+1      1       Begin Hd - начало раздела: номер головки (стороны). 
+2      2       Begin Sec/Cyl – начало раздела: сектор/цилиндр. 
+4      1       System Code – код файловой системы (см. табл. 6.4).
+5      1       Ending Hd – конец раздела : номер головки. 
+6      2       Ending Sec/Cyl – конец раздела : сектор/цилиндр последнего сектора. 
+8      4       Starting Sector – логический номер начального сектора раздела (адрес в
                системе LBA). 
+0Ch    4       Num Sectors – размер раздела (число секторов)
```